# AngulagJS MVC Web API 2 Login

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a login page where im not using the aspnetusers table but my member table.
How can I create my own token, authorization/authentication?

So far this is my code:
web api 2 controller for api call and
signin controller js

```
"use strict";

app.controller('MemberSignInController', MemberSignInController);

MemberSignInController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', 'toaster', '$rootScope', 'DataServiceFactory']

function MemberSignInController($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, toaster, $rootScope, DataServiceFactory) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.member = {};

    vm.signIn = function () {
        vm.showMessage = false;

        var params = {
            cardNumber: vm.member.username,
            password: vm.member.password
        };

        $http.post('api/member/login', params).then(
            function (response) {
                $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                DataServiceFactory.Id = response.data.memberId;             
                window.location = '#!/profile';
            },
            function (response) {           
                toaster.pop('error', "Sign In Failed", response.data, 5000);
                $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
                window.location = '#!/signIn';
            }
        );

    }
}
```

so far this is my code yet and its working but when i refresh my page, the login userdata is clear, i have to logout to login again to be able to see the data.

Please help me, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login userdata is cleared on refresh because it is not stored anywhere.

Since you are using AngularJS with Webapi, you need to understand your calls are sessionless.

You have to use cookies to store data after successful login, and on refresh you need to check if data is available on cookie.

If data is available in cookie, keep the session or redirect to login page.

On logout, clear the cookies.